# How to Validate NTP builds?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, build, ntp

I just ported NTP to a new operation system and I want to validate my port.
In the NTP source directory there are two directories with test code

- ./sntp/tests
- /tests

In the sntp/tests directory there's a binary built called tests_runner but no matter how or where I run it from nothing happens other than errors.

Documentation on these test seem slim, does anyone know how to make use of these tests?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to verify a NTP service is running correctly is using the *ntpq* utility that is provided in most NTP distributions.

Run ntpq command-line tool optionally with a target NTP host and use various commands to check its status. The command rv (short for readvar) is used to read system or peer variables. Run ntpq without a hostname argument to check the local machine.

```
> ntpq pool.ntp.org
ntpq> rv
associd=0 status=061b leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, leap_event,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p2@1.3265-o Sun Jun 28 00:17:46 UTC 2015 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64", leap=00,
stratum=2, precision=-23, rootdelay=4.709, rootdisp=36.700,
refid=129.6.15.29,
reftime=d979ca76.f5099c68  Sat, Aug 15 2015 10:25:58.957,
clock=d979cf47.1a063b44  Sat, Aug 15 2015 10:46:31.101, peer=19946,
tc=10, mintc=3, offset=-0.317125, frequency=6.099, sys_jitter=2.636560,
clk_jitter=0.277, clk_wander=0.022, tai=1
ntpq>
```

If the NTP service is not synchronized then it would typically show a reftime time with 0 value and/or stratum=16 with refid=INIT meaning it is stuck in the initialization state.

```
processor="x86", system="Windows", leap=11, stratum=16, precision=-10,
rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=1.590, refid=INIT
reftime=00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  1:28:16.000
```

Ntpq utility is also available in the Windows binary distribution of NTP:
https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm